# Error al inserta datos en base de datos MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Me da el siguiente error `Column 'Nombre' cannot be null` al intentar guardar un registro en la base de datos

```
Private sub Create(ByVal cliente As Cliente)
    Using cn = New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("default").ToString())
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd as MySqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CLIENTE(nombre, fecha) VALUES(@nombre, DATE_FORMAT(@fecha, '%y%m%d'))"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", cliente.Nombre)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", cliente.Fecha)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End sub
```

Pero en la base de datos si funciona muy bien

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTE(nombre, fecha) VALUES('JOEL', DATE_FORMAT('2017-06-13', '%y%m%d'))
```

Comment: Estas seguro de que `cliente.Nombre` no es null? Depura el código a ver si trae algun valor

Comment: Ya lo depure si me trae datos, tengo una campo que es clave primaria pero auto-incremet

Comment: Y si cambias tu query para ponerle un valor fijo al nombre,algo asi:`cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CLIENTE(nombre, fecha) VALUES('Joel', DATE_FORMAT(@fecha, '%y%m%d'))"`? solo por probar a ver si te da el mismo error

Comment: Por el error, es posible que el valor recuperado con: `cliente.Nombre` sea **nulo**. Para depurar, podrías tratar de imprimir el valor que te arroja `cliente.Nombre`  en alguna parte. Aunque en vez de `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` , se **recomienda usar `cmd.Parameters.Add` por varios motivos, entre ellos la seguridad de los datos**. [Aquí tienes algunos de los motivos esgrimidos](http://devtroce.com/2013/03/19/parameters-add-vs-parameters-addwithvalue/) y un ejemplo sencillo de su uso.

Answer (score -5):

Por que mezclas parámetros de un procedimiento almacenado con un texto plano???

Si lo quieres poner en texto lo haría así:

```
Private sub Create(ByVal cliente As Cliente)
    Using cn = New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("default").ToString())
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd as MySqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CLIENTE(nombre, fecha) VALUES("+cliente.Nombre+", DATE_FORMAT("+cliente.Fecha+", '%y%m%d'))
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End sub
```

En caso de que quieras hacerlo con un procedimiento: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-using.html

Comment: O sea, que la solución es exponer todo el código a la posibilidad de [`SqlInjection`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)?

Comment: @Pikoh quizás desconoce el tema de SqlInjection. Rafael, revisa https://www.owasp.org :)

Comment: Por que dices eso?

Comment: Nunca,**nunca**, se debe generar una query sql concatenando strings. Para eso existen las consultas parametrizadas.

Comment: Además debajo le he puesto como hacerlo con procedimientos.

Comment: Vaya,tengo que poner al menos 15 caracteres. La respuesta es **no**. En serio,**siempre** se deben usar consultas parametrizadas, todo lo demás serán problemas en algun momento